# jQuery $.post putting form input in url

Tags: jquery, http-post

I'm currently trying to implement a basic authentication system using an HTML form and a POST request.  When I press the button to send the information to the server, the page is redirected to itself, but with the serialized form input appended to the url.

For example: The username and password entered are 'username' and 'password', respectively.  The page goes from

www.example.com/index.html

to

www.example.com/index.html?username=username&password=password

I have this exact same code working fine in another page.  I've also tried moving this to three different web servers to see if that was the problem.

**Here's the code:**

*HTML form:*

```
<form id='loginForm'>
    <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='Username'>
    <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password'>
    <button onClick='login()'>Log In</button>
</form>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
function login(){
    $.post('mobile_php/login.php', $('#loginForm').serialize(), function(data){
        //code handling data in here        
     });
}
```

*login.php*

```
<?php
    echo "success";
?>
```

When I use the debugger to find out what's happening, the callback function is never entered.  The browser gets to the `$.post` call, but then skips over the body of it and finishes.  I'm currently using Chrome, but I tested in Firefox and had the same problem.

One thing of note, when I open the Network tab in the Chrome developer tools console, it shows the request for login.php is canceled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because your form is being submit in the normal manner, via `get` by default, which is why the querystring is appearing.

You need to attach your JS code to the `submit` event of the `form` itself, not the click of the button. Try this:

```
<form id="loginForm">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <button>Log In</button>
</form>
```

```js
$('#loginForm').submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the normal form submission as you are using AJAX.
    $.post('mobile_php/login.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data){
        //code handling data in here        
    });
});
```